# Bezug auf Genitivnomen: Wann wird Dativ bevorzugt?

Tags: grammar, usage, grammatical-case, dative, genitive

> (a) Mannheim liegt am Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, des Rheins und des Neckars.
>
> (b) Mannheim liegt am Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, dem Rhein und dem Neckar.

Laut einer Antwort zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12086/article-when-referring-to-noun-in-genitive-case) scheint es, dass man hier tendenziell wie in (b) den Dativ benutzen würde, denn ein Doppelgenitiv könnte als Teil einer Liste missverstanden werden.

Ich möchte aber wissen, inwieweit diese Logik gilt. In unseren kurzen Beispielssätzen kann es kaum zu Missverständnissen kommen. Würde man dann lieber den Genitiv wie in (a) benutzen, oder bleibt man doch mit dem Dativ? Wenn es dazu auch Referenzen von autoritativen Quellen gäbe, wäre es schön.

Comment: Für mich sind solche Kasusabweichungen zwischen Apposition und Bezugswort immer falsch. Daher wäre die Antwort: Ich würde nie wechseln und auch anderen davon abraten. In diesem speziellen Fall gibt es aber eine alternative Deutung: _liegt an 1. dem Zusammenfluß zweier Flüsse, 2. dem Rhein, 3. dem Neckar_. (_Kreuzung_ paßt auch nicht sonderlich gut.) Ist sicher nicht gemeint, könnte aber in anderen Fällen Sinn ergeben: _Koblenz liegt am Zusammenfluß zweier Flüsse, dem Hunsrück und dem Maifeld._

Comment: Ich würde in (a) ein *nämlich* nach dem Komma einfügen und schon ist es grammatikalisch korrekt und eindeutig.

Comment: Gerade der Dativ suggeriert doch eine Liste (von 3 Elementen), während es             eine Liste von 2en ist. Zusammenfluss wessen? Des X und des Y.

Comment: Ich würde nach dem Komma den gleichen Fall benutzen wie davor. In diesem Fall Dativ. Wenn jedoch Genitiv schon im ersten Teil benutzt wird, würde ich es auch danach verwenden. Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher das ist auch so eine Art Regel, beweisen kann ich es jedoch nicht ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In welchem Kasus die Flüsse hier stehen müssen, hängt ganz davon ab, worauf sich der durch das Komma abgetrennte Satzteil (Apposition) bezieht.

Normalerweise wird man damit spezifizieren wollen, welche Flüsse bei Mannheim zusammenfließen, daher wäre ein Bezug auf *Zusammenfluss* anzunehmen. Das muss mit dem Genitiv (1) oder der Präposition *von* (2, erfordert Dativ) geschehen.

> *Mannheim liegt …*
>
> 1. ***am Zusammenfluss** zweier Flüsse, **des Rheins und des Neckars**.* (a)
> 2. ***am Zusammenfluss** zweier Flüsse, **von Rhein und Neckar**.*

Stattdessen können auch die beiden Flüsse näher benannt werden, ohne Artikel und Präposition (3). Dazu sollte man schriftlich den Doppelpunkt verwenden, aber Gedankenstrich oder Komma sind m.E. auch akzeptabel.

> 3. *am Zusammenfluss **zweier Flüsse: Rhein und Neckar**.*

Alternativ könnte auch das Verb mit seiner Präposition *an*, die den Dativ verlangt, wiederaufgegriffen werden. Dann wird das Zusammenfließen allerdings nur impliziert. Da hier allerdings *am* und nicht *an dem* steht, muss die Präposition in der Apposition wiederholt werden, was entweder für beide Flüsse gemeinsam (4) oder separat (5) geschehen kann.

> 4. *am Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **an Rhein und Neckar**.*
> 5. *am Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **am Rhein und am Neckar**.*

Die Alternative (b) aus der Frage (6) ist nicht völlig ungrammatisch, jedoch stilistisch unschön, weil der Dativmarker *m* schon in der Präposition enthalten ist, aber in den Artikeln *dem* wiederholt wird.

> 6. ***a[n** de]m Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **dem Rhein und dem Neckar**.* (b)

Die Präposition *am* könnte jeweils explizit in *an dem* aufgelöst werden, aber das ist heute fast schon unidiomatisch. Damit ergäben sich mindestens vier weitere akzeptable Varianten:

> 7. ***an** dem Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **Rhein und Neckar**.*
> 8. ***an** dem Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **dem Rhein und dem Neckar**.*
> 9. *an dem Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **an dem Rhein und dem Neckar**.*
> 10. *an dem Zusammenfluss zweier Flüsse, **an dem Rhein und an dem Neckar**.*

Zur Übung kann man sich überlegen, wie der Satz für Passau aussieht, wo **der** Inn in **die** Donau fließt, oder für Deggendorf, wo **die** Isar ebenfalls in die Donau mündet. Neutrale Flüsse (mit *das*) gibt es m.W. nicht.

Comment: Es gibt Bäche, deren Name irgendetwas mit *-wasser* ist; das ist dann Neutrum.

Comment: Insgesamt finde ich die Antwort schwer verständlich bzw. unübersichtlich, weil inhaltlich völlig verschiedene Sätze einfach nebeneinander stehen. Die Verweise am Anfang helfen wenig.

Comment: @chirlu Ich habe den Block mal ein bisschen umsortiert und aufgetrennt.